# Using namespaces to work with shadowed identifiers

Tags: random, namespaces, scheme, racket

I'm working on a simple game using Racket (homework assignment). The requirements instruct me to create a computer player named random which utilizes the default random number generator.
This snippet of code illustrates my issue:

```
(define (random)
  (random (10))) ; should be random number call
```

I'm used to the C convention for namespaces:

```
std::string
```

Does Racket offer anything along those lines?
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/module-require.html with regards to the `prefix-in` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`prefix-in`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._prefix-in%29%29) to prefix the exports of the standard library with some namespacing prefix.  For example:

```
#lang racket
(require (prefix-in std:: racket))
(define (* x)
  (std::* x x))
```

shows that we can shadow the bindings from `#lang racket`, but still get at them through the prefixed identifiers.

Traditionally, the prefixes that people use are a little simpler, like:

```
#lang racket
(require (prefix-in r: racket))
(define (* x)
  (r:* x x))
```